# In BigCommerce, Where do I place the Lucky Orange Email Implementation Code?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce, email

**I am using the BigCommerce cornerstone theme.**

Where do I place the Lucky Orange Email Implementation Code?

I placed the code in the "Footer Scripts." But this didn't work.

The code from Lucky Orange is below.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

window.__lo_site_id = 120178;

(function() {
    var wa = document.createElement('script'); wa.type = 'text/javascript';         
    wa.async = true;

    wa.src = 'https://d10lpsik1i8c69.cloudfront.net/w.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];         
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wa, s);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://help.luckyorange.com/article/93-how-to-install-in-bigcommerce

Comment: Thank you for the article. I placed the code as recommended. For some reason I am still receiving this error e-mail. please see snap shot here https://snag.gy/bmkCiQ.jpg

Comment: Hmm, I can see the script in the page source, so we know it's there. I think your best next step would be to reach out to Lucky Orange tech support for troubleshooting help. They'll be best equipped to provide advice on installing their app.